# tokbox: how to determine when participant's audio is muted

Tags: android, audio, opentok, tokbox

How to get event when your participant turned off audio?
`Subscriber` has a `VideoListener` which is notified when video state is changed, but how to get events for audio?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SubscriberKit.AudioLevelListener to see what the audio level of the subscriber is. This is based on the logarithmic scale ranging from 0 to 1.0 where 0 means no audio.

You can find more information on the implementation here: https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/

Update (06/10/20)

You can set a listener for the [stream properties](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.StreamPropertiesListener.html) to determine if the stream's properties have changed while the stream is active. After setting this listener, the SDK will dispatch events each time a publisher mutes or unmutes their audio or video.

Comment: unfortunately I have to determine event when user has muted audio to indicate this on ui like crossed microphone icon. So this way is not suitable.